# jQuery function only applied after refresh

Tags: jquery, json, load, getjson, ready

I'm using $.getJSON(...) to load JSON data (images) to my HTML web page, the getJSON() function gets called when the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

After that I use the montage.js script to order the image into a responsive grid. This function gets called when the full page is loaded and ready:

```
$(window).load(function() {...}
```

Still when I open the page the images do not get orderd, only when I refresh the page the montage.js script gets applied and the images become a grid.

getJSON:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "images.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data.images, function( key, val ) {
            //
        });    
    });
});
```

Comment: try loading montage.js on success of your json response

Comment: I appended the getJSON code, can you give me a simple example how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "images.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data.images, function( key, val ) {
            //
        });    
    }).done(function(){

        $('image').montage(); //do something like this to call montage for your image
   });
});
```

Since success is deprecated for $.getJSON youll be using `.done`().